# Descompactação de arquivos com espaço no nome

Tags: linux, shell-script

Estou tentando descompactar uma grande massa de arquivos no linux e estou tentando usando um for que está assim:

```
for z in *.zip; do unzip $z ; done
```

mas recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> unzip:  cannot find or open divide, divide.zip or divide.ZIP. unzip: 
>   cannot find or open install, install.zip or install.ZIP.

O problema maior se deve porque há espaços nos nomes, etc.

Eu já fiz um outro `for` substituindo os espaços por '_' mas eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de descompactar sem substituir os espaços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode inserir aspas duplas no *for* e no comando *unzip* que o *bash* irá trabalhar bem com nomes de arquivos em que existe espaço:

```
for z in "*.zip"; do unzip "$z" ; done
```

Comment: Cuidado: as primeiras aspas estão a mais -- talvez: `for z in *.zip; do unzip "$z" ; done`  para expandir o `*` ?

Comment: Não, as aspas duplas são justamente a questão, porque o colega estava com problemas para nomes de arquivo com espaços.

Answer (score 1):

É possível, para isso, tem q dar um jeito de separar seus arquivos. Como a divisão dos seus arquivos será pela quebra de linha (por causa do `ls`), usaremos ela para dividir suas *Strings*.

```
zfiles=$(ls *.zip) # lista os arquivos .zip e armazena em $zfiles
IFS='
' # IFS é a variável responsável por definir o caractere da quebra de linha
lista=($zfiles) # criará um array com os arquivos

for x in "${!lista[@]}"; do
    unzip "$x" #como os nomes terão espaço, mantenha o $x dentro de aspas duplas
done
```

Dento de `IFS` tem uma quebra de linha, e no `for` a `!` é obrigatória em `${!lista[@]}`, para que se percorra o vetor